# Find ratio between two signals

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

We are recording two fluorescences signals from a mouse with an optical fiber. The mouse is a control one so the signals have different intensity but have the same shape.

I want to find and plot the ratio of the two signals and I want my ratio to be stable. In fact when we'll test a normal mouse we want to use that ratio to eliminate noises.

Plot of the two signals:
[image: Plot of the two signals]

I used that code to try to do the ratio

```
value = xlsread('souris.xlsx'); %Open file with the two signals
yGreenFluo = value(:,2) - 1585; %The 0 for the laser is at 1585
yRedFluo = value(:,3) - 1585; %The 0 for the laser is at 1585
yGreenNormalize = yGreenFluo /norm(yGreenFluo) ; %Normalize
yRedNormalize = yRedFluo /norm(yRedFluo); %Normalize
coeff = polyfit(yRedNormalize, yGreenNormalize, 1); %Do a linear regression
b = coeff(2);
ratio = (yGreenNormalize - b) / yRedNormalize;
```

So now I show what I get when I plot the ratio

plot of the ratio:
[image: plot of the ratio]

As you can see it doesn't work... I have really no clue how to do it...

Comment: Try posting a [mcve] . We want to copy paste->work!

Comment: What is the variable yV? Also, I'm not convinced `norm()` is  really the function you want to normalize your signals here...

Comment: norm is not normalize, norm is the L2 norm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: @AnderBiguri that's what I was getting at :)

Comment: I will edit my post as soon as I can thank you for helping me

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce my signals in matlab so i send you the link where you can download 'souris.xlsx' ... 
I am sorry for that...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5JOJuClAu6LWpFR0RwMXZBZTg